# IIS UrlRewrite Not Working on 404 Requests

Tags: iis, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to remove the "Server" header from IIS 8.0. I have installed UrlRewrite and added the following code to my web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
    <rule name="Remove Server header">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

However, when a request comes in that generates a 404, the "Server" header is still included.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

I am using Web API 2 running on Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Add an owin middleware first in your pipeline:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        ctx.Response.OnSendingHeaders(state =>
        {
            var res = (OwinResponse)state;
            res.Headers.Remove("Server");
        }, ctx.Response);

        await next();
    });

    //...
}
```

Comment: I have that already and it works great for API calls, but it isn't getting hit for static content (i.e. .js, .html, .css, etc).

Comment: Try adding `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true` to the `<modules>` section in your Web.config

Comment: Everything that i have read says that turning this on will have a large performance impact and is not recommended.